# Verifying a proof for $(\sqrt{b_n})\rightarrow \sqrt{b}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

My attempt to proof $(\sqrt{b_n})\rightarrow \sqrt{b}$

We note that $(\sqrt{b_n}-\sqrt{b})(\frac{\sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt{b}})=\frac{b_n-b}{\sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt{b}}.$

Then $\forall\epsilon\gt0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|\sqrt{b_n}-\sqrt{b}|=|\frac{b_n-b}{\sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt{b}}|=\frac{|b_n-b|}{|\sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt{b}|}\lt\epsilon, \forall n\gt N$

Given that $|b_n-b|\rightarrow0$, we conclude that $\frac{|b_n-b|}{|\sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt{b}|}\rightarrow \frac{0}{|\sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt{b}|}=0.$

Thus we claim that $|\sqrt{b_n}-\sqrt{b}|\rightarrow 0$, and so $\sqrt{b_n}\rightarrow\sqrt{b},\forall n >N$. $\square$

Please let me know if my attempt make sense. Appreciate any comments.

Comment: I don't understand how you've proved the assertion in line 3 $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N\in\Bbb N,\forall n>N, \frac{\lvert b_n-b\rvert}{\lvert \sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt b\rvert}<\epsilon$$

Comment: Also, I cannot assign an interpretation - as of content - to the statement in line 4 $$\frac{\lvert b_n-b\rvert}{\lvert{b_n}+\sqrt{b}\rvert}\to\frac 0{\lvert{b_n}+\sqrt {b}\rvert}$$

Comment: @Gae.S. thank you for your comments. I see now That like 3 does not make sense as this is what I have to proof; and I've state this without any prior work. I'll try to work on line 4 to give come content that would establish the limit.

Comment: Take#2. $(\sqrt b_n)\rightarrow b_n\iff(\sqrt b_n-b_n)\rightarrow 0$. Given $\sqrt b_n-b_n=\frac{b_n-b}{\sqrt b_n+b_n}$ it's sufficient to show that $(\frac{b_n-b}{\sqrt b_n+b_n})\rightarrow 0$. Given that $(b_n-b)\rightarrow 0$ by the quotient rule $(\frac{b_n-b}{\sqrt b_n+b_n})\rightarrow 0. \square$

Comment: Why quotient rule? I don't think you've proved that $\sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt b$ converges (all the more to a non-zero number).

Comment: You're right, I can't use quotient rule as I haven't shown that denominator doesn't tend to 0. But I can use product rule. How about the this? Given that $(b_n-b)\rightarrow 0$ by the product rule $(\frac{b_n-b}{\sqrt b_n+b_n})=(b_n-b)\frac{1}{(\sqrt b_n+b_n)}\rightarrow 0(\sqrt b_n+b_n)=0. \square$

Comment: The exact same thing: you have not proved that $\frac1{\sqrt{b_n}+b}$ converges.

Comment: My thinking is that whichever value $\frac{1}{(\sqrt b_n+b_n)}$ converges to if $(b_n-b)\rightarrow 0$ then the product is still 0; by the product rule. I start doubting if I'm going in the right direction at all.

Comment: Also, for some reason at some point in the comments you've decided that you don't like $\frac1{\sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt b}$ anymore, and you started writing other stuff (and partially so did I). Anyways, for all you have said so far, $\frac1{\sqrt{b_n}+\sqrt b}$ might not converge at all. If you want to go that way you should state a reason why it should converge to something, and then explore the two cases of when that something is $0$ and when it is not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101317/discussion-between-u1731182-and-gae-s).

Comment: We are given that $\sqrt b_n\ge0,\forall n\in N$.When $b=0$ it trivially holds that$\sqrt b_n\rightarrow 0$. When $b\neq0$, we have $\sqrt b_n-\sqrt b=\frac{b_n-b}{(\sqrt b_n+\sqrt b)}\lt\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt b}$. Does this make sense?

Comment: $b\ne 0$ is ok with modulus on the numerator, but it's correct. The fact that $\sqrt{b_n}\to 0$ when $b_n\to 0^+$ is part of the assignment, therefore you must prove it.